# displaying a Microsoft word file in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have an application developed in ASP.net MVC4 visual studio 2012. I have a page on which I have to display a word document. The word document is already uploaded at server from a different page. At this page my program loads that document do some changes and shows a preview by opening the updated word file. The application works fine in visual studio, but crashes after deployment.

```
filename = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + branchP.OfferletterPath;
outfilename = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"Temp\OfferLetter" + "_1";

object Missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Application app = null;
            Document doc = null;

            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            doc = app.Documents.Open(filename, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing);
            var salary = 0;

            WordUtils.FindReplaceAnywhere(app, "<mobileno>", jobCandidate.MobilePhoneNo);
            WordUtils.FindReplaceAnywhere(app, "<currentdate>", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            WordUtils.FindReplaceAnywhere(app, "<name>", jobCandidate.JobCandidateName);
            WordUtils.FindReplaceAnywhere(app, "<address>", jobCandidate.Address);
            WordUtils.FindReplaceAnywhere(app, "<designation>", jobCandidate.JobTitle);
            WordUtils.FindReplaceAnywhere(app, "<doj>", jobCandidate.EmpJoiningDate.ToString());
            WordUtils.FindReplaceAnywhere(app, "<salary>", salary.ToString());

            Object beforeRow = Type.Missing;
            int i = 2;
            double amt = 0;

            if (doc.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                doc.Tables[1].Select();
                Table tbl = doc.Tables[1];
                foreach (var jc in _entities.JobCandidatePayStructures.Where(jc => jc.JobCandidateId == jobCandidate.Id))
                {
                    tbl.Rows.Add(beforeRow);
                    tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = jc.Code;
                    tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Bold = 0;

                    tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = jc.Amount.ToString();
                    tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Bold = 0;

                    amt = amt + jc.Amount;
                    i++;
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(beforeRow);
                tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = "Gross Salary";
                tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Bold = 1;
                tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = amt.ToString();
                tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Bold = 1;
            }


            doc.SaveAs(outfilename, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing);
            app.Visible = true;
```

The above code is working fine in visual studio, but when I am executing above function after deployment its throwing following exception:

```
This command is not available because no document is open.
Exception occurred at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.get_ActiveDocument()
at HRIS.Models.WordUtils.FindReplaceAnywhere(Application app, String findText, String replaceText)
```

If anyone has worked on a similar application please suggest a way forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `but crashes after deployment` is not a very clear problem description. I would recommend you to start with showing your code and then explaining any possible error messages you might be getting.

Comment: Do you have any sort of logging on the server that could show you what is causing the crash?

Comment: It is not recommend that you use Office Automation in a server environment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application".